# How to query documents with specific ordering in mongoengine

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have a list with visited page IDs like:
`visited = [10, 5, 18, 9, ...]`

Using '__in' operator in query returns QuerySet of needed objects, but not in 'visited' list order:
`docs = Documents.objects(id__in=visited)`
In result: `[<Document 5>, <Document 9>, <Document 10>, ...]`

Is it possible to order QuerySet by list which I used for querying documents Without loops and querying DB with each ID?

Comment: What order you want to get?

Comment: QuerySet has an order_by() method you can use.

Comment: [<Document 10>, <Document 5>, <Document 18>, <Document 9>, ...] like in list of visited pages

Comment: Order_by sorting in 2 sides I guess: from min to max and reversed.

Comment: At db level for MySQL & PostgreSQL: http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/django-create-a-queryset-from-a-list-preserving-order.html    may it helpfull to convert to mongoengine

Comment: Thanks Jameel. This solution is suitable for a small number of documents, and that if there will be over 10k?